# In ZFC, is there a set of objects that satisfy x=x

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Is there a set of objects that are equal to themselves? In other words, is this true: $$\exists y \forall x (x\in y \iff x=x)$$

Intuitively, It seems to be the set of all sets and hence false. How can I prove this?

Comment: No, there is not such a *set*. It is a proper class however, commonly denoted by $V$: the universe of all sets.

Comment: I agree. Intuitively, I can see that it would be the set of all sets. How can I prove this? To show that the statement I've mentioned in the post is false in ZFC?

Comment: Yeah... a bit of a brain freeze on my part.  As everything is equal to itself this would be the verboten "set of all sets".  It's the universe or class of all sets but not a set itself as no set can have itself as an element.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true.

If there did exist such a set $y$, then by the axiom of separation we'd have
$$ \exists z \forall x [x \in z \Leftrightarrow (x \in y \wedge x \not\in x )] $$
That is, there would exist a set $z$ given by $z = \{ x \in y \mid x \not\in x \}$.

But then both $z \in z$ and $z \not\in z$ lead to a contradiction.

[This is Russell's paradox, for what it's worth.]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question: do we have a set of objects that are definable in ZFC (basically set of terms in ZFC)? In other words, in $\forall x (x=x)$ which is a true statement, what are the objects we refer to when we say "for all objects" or "for all $x$"?